# How to use two arrays to form an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, append, javascript-objects

I have two object arrays as:

```
array1 = [Object, Object, Object]
array2 = [Object, Object, Object]
```

where each Object in array1 is:

```
{property1 : "somevalue"}
```

and in array2:

```
{property1 : Object, property2 : "somevalue"}
```

where Object has its own set of properties. Therefore the structure of both arrays is different.

I need to append these two arrays to form a single array like that of a json format.
The final structure **should** appear like this:

{

"root1" : array1,
"root2" : array2

}

Please help.
The final json that I want will appear kind of like this:

```
{ 
  "root1" : [
  {property1 : "somevalue"},
  {property1 : "somevalue"},
  {property1 : "somevalue"}
             ],

  "root2" : [
  {property1 : Object, property2 : "somevalue"},
  {property1 : Object, property2 : "somevalue"},
  {property1 : Object, property2 : "somevalue"}
             ]
}
```

How do I create this object in runtime?

Comment: json like structure? an object!

Comment: give us the JSON format for the two arrays

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: you could use the last example directly. what is wrong with it?

Comment: Finally the json should appear like this {

"root1" : [{property1 : "somevalue"}, {property1 : "somevalue"}, {property1 : "somevalue"}],
"root2" : [{property1 : Object, property2 : "somevalue"}, {property1 : Object, property2 : "somevalue"}, {property1 : Object, property2 : "somevalue"}]

}

Comment: So although you *say* you want "a single array", what you actually want is a single *object* that has the two original arrays as *separate* properties? The arrays themselves won't be merged with each other in any way?

Comment: yes, and what does not work?

Comment: Your update is more confusing than explaining

Comment: @nnnnnn yes correct

Comment: @mplungjan I only mentioned the entire json so the structure is clear. What is it that's made the question more complex?

Comment: You use of property1 in array 2 is confusing. Use better examples

Comment: @mplungjan next time I'll remember. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like that:

```js
var arr1 = [{prop: "Value 1"}, {prop: "Value 2"}, {prop: "Value 3"}];

var arr2 = [{prop: "Value A", prop1: "Value Z"}, {prop: "Value B", prop1: "Value Y"}, {prop: "Value C", prop1: "Value X"}];

//as object
var result = { root1: arr1, root2: arr2 };

// as array
var mergedArrays = [].concat(arr1, arr2);
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log("Result", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your new object with array:

```
var myArrays{

"root1" : array1,
"root2" : array2

}
```

Lets convert it to a JSON string

```
var myJson = JSON.stringify(myArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use push() method on Array as below

```
var mergedArrays = [];
mergedArrays.push(array1);
mergedArrays.push(array2);
JSON.stringify(mergedArrays);
```